# CFSocket callback not resetting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, callback

I have a problem with a CFSocket.
I need to enable and disable the
callbacks from the socket and for this i use

```
CFSocketEnableCallBacks(cfSocket, kCFSocketReadCallBack);
```

and

```
CFSocketDisableCallBacks(cfSocket, kCFSocketReadCallBack);
```

But, when you wake up the callback I get old messages.
is probably a problem of reset (?)
How do I reset everything before disabling
callback?

Comment: Which socket flags are set?  Check with `CFSocketGetSocketFlags`.